# How to suppress zsh completion list?

Tags: zsh

When I press `Tab`, if the completion list is too long to be shown on my terminal window, `zsh` will still print out the full list and display a `$PROMPT` afterwards. If I wish to use the menu given by `zstyle ":completion:*" menu select`, the completion list will probably be displayed twice. However in `fish` I will get a suppressed list containing only first few items followed by `...and 100 more rows` or so. Is there any way to modify the way `zsh` printing out the completion list?

Answer (score 1):

If I refer to the question in the title, you may use

```
setopt menucomplete
```

in which case zsh will *always* complete on available completion(s) ; if there are several it will fill in with the topmost item. This way you'll skip the initial completions display in the ambiguous case.